# Advice for Modeling a Rare Response (y)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, model

**My Question 1:**

Is it possible to create a "good" predictive model with only 40/100,000 rows of data containing a "y" (response) value greater than or equal to 1?

**My Question 2:**

Is it a better idea to treat this as a classification problem to try and predict the probability that a given row will have a `Success` or not (binary - either Success is greater than or equal to `1`, or it's not.)?

**My Question 3:**

How would somebody that knows what their doing approach this problem?

**The Scenario**

Imagine you have 100,000 rows of data, 11 predictor columns (X) (I'll call them 'features'), 1 response column (y) (I'll call 'response').

Challenges

1. 4 of the 11 columns are text features
2. Literally 99.96% of the 100,000 rows have a value of 0 (response = 0)
3. The numeric data is highly correlated / co-linear*

*Here's what I mean by co-linear.  Imagine you are an advertiser that shows ads to consumers.  Each time you show an ad, that is 1 ad `impression`.  You also track how many times somebody clicks your ad.  Thus, a `click` can only happen when an ad impression happens first.  Likewise, when someone clicks, it `cost`s you money.  Thus, cost is dependent on clicks.  `Impressions`, `Clicks` and `Cost` are some of the numeric features in your dataset.  To complicate matters further, some of the other numeric features in the dataset are *computed **ratios*** of Impressions, Clicks and Cost (ex: `Clicks / Impressions = CTR`).

Here's what a Correlation table looks like for those three metrics.

```
                  Impressions    Clicks      Cost  Success
Correlation                                                        
Impressions          1.000000                             
Clicks               0.775137  1.000000                      
Cost                 0.939176  0.871322  1.000000               
Success              0.615803  0.730030  0.684967 1.000000
```

Here's a general idea of what my data looks like:

```
   Campaign Ad group     Keyword  Max. CPC Match type  Impressions  Clicks  \
0    TextC1  TextA12   TextK3479      4.63      Exact         1113     143   
1    TextC9  TextA30   TextK2539      9.85      Broad          864      36   
2    TextC1   TextA8   TextK6773      6.10      Exact         1093     179   
3    TextC4  TextA13  TextK43427      4.41      Exact            0       0   
4    TextC1  TextA15  TextK19243      4.41     Phrase            0       0   
5    TextC1   TextA8   TextK8238      5.87      Broad          396       5   
6   TextC15   TextA8    TextK214      6.16      Broad           67       5   
7    TextC7  TextA19   TextK9373      5.61     Phrase            1       1   
8    TextC6   TextA6  TextK22891      8.83      Broad            1       0   
9    TextC1  TextA10  TextK27725      8.83     Phrase            0       0   
10   TextC5  TextA12   TextK5152      4.41     Phrase            7       1   
11   TextC5   TextA8   TextK1271      4.41      Exact            2       1   
12  TextC15  TextA19     TextK35      4.41     Phrase           17       1   
13   TextC6   TextA5  TextK94139      4.41     Phrase            0       0   

        CTR  Avg. CPC   Cost  Avg. position  Success  
0    12.85%      0.40  57.86            1.1        3  
1     4.17%      1.55  55.91            1.5        0  
2    16.38%      0.31  55.12            1.0        0  
3     0.00%      0.00   0.00            0.0        0  
4     0.00%      0.00   0.00            0.0        0  
5     1.26%      0.42   2.09            1.1        1  
6     7.46%      0.97   4.87            1.7        1  
7   100.00%      1.14   1.14            1.0        1  
8     0.00%      0.00   0.00            3.0        0  
9     0.00%      0.00   0.00            0.0        0  
10   14.29%      0.85   0.85            1.0        0  
11   50.00%      0.78   0.78            1.0        0  
12    5.88%      0.81   0.81            2.4        0  
13    0.00%      0.00   0.00            0.0        0
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but my above scenario **violates several assumptions of linear regression**.

**Other things I've tried**
Convert text columns to features of count vectors and binary categorical variables.  ElasticNet, LASSO, LARS.  Standardizing / scaling numeric features to have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1.  Overall, nothing I've tried really gives me reliable results.  What I've found is that essentially `Clicks` is the best feature for predicting `Success` because a Success can't happen without a Click technically.